I can't get prettier+eslint to work with TypeScript projects in VSCode
I can't get the prettier-eslint vscode extension to execute prettier in typescript projects.
The docs for prettier-eslint vscode extension says to install the following for typescript projects (see docs):
yarn add -D prettier@^3.1.0 eslint@^8.52.0 prettier-eslint@^16.1.2 @typescript-eslint/parser@^5.0.1 typescript@^4.4.4`

But version @typescript-eslint/parser@^5.0.1 does not exist in npmjs but 5.1.0 does and the typescript example in the plugin's project uses 5.1.0.
Here's the issue I reported to the prettier-eslint project in github. It was unanswered and went stale after a month.
I've tried many other package numbers and searched the web for clues, to no avail.
Even the example typescript app from the plugin's project has the same problem- eslint works but prettier does not.
https://github.com/idahogurl/vs-code-prettier-eslint
Output from prettier plugin:
["ERROR" - 9:45:51 PM] Invalid version
Error: Invalid version
    at t.isAboveV3 (c:\Users\ken\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-11.0.0\dist\extension.js:1:25515)
    at t.default.getSelectors (c:\Users\ken\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-11.0.0\dist\extension.js:1:11796)
    at t.default.handleActiveTextEditorChanged (c:\Users\ken\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-11.0.0\dist\extension.js:1:11123)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)```

